# VBO: not drawing correctly. Manual drawing works

Tags: opengl

so I will need to edit this question. As stated in one of the comments, I changed to rendering method to use buffers. However, the geometry isn't being drawn correctly. If I use the same buffer and draw the vertices manually, it looks alright (without the texture though, something is messed up with it). I also tried constructing a buffer with just vertex information but that didn't help at all.

```
void ModelHandler::DrawModels(){


    //go through each of the models
    for(int i=0;i<Models3D.size();i++){

        //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        //glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, Models3D[i]->object.m_pVertice);


        //now draw all the material groups with their vertices for the model
        for(int j=0;j<Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups.size();j++){


            //Drawing the vertices manually from the buffer object seems to work
            /*
            for(int lj=0;lj<Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->m_vecgroupVerticeIndex.size();lj++){

                int mtlIndex2 = Models3D[i]->object.FindMaterial(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->mtlName);
                bool tOn = false;

                //check if there was a texture for this material
                if(Models3D[i]->object.materials[mtlIndex2]->texturePresent){

                    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                    //glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
                    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Models3D[i]->object.materials[mtlIndex2]->textureIDDiffuse);
                    tOn = true;


                }

                if(tOn){
                    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
                    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
                    glVertex3f (0.0+5, 0.0, -2.0f);
                    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
                    glVertex3f (1.4f+5, 0.0, -2.0f);
                    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
                    glVertex3f (1.4f+5, -1.0, -2.0f);
                    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
                    glVertex3f (0.0f+5, -1.0, -2.0f);
                    glEnd ();               
                }



                glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

                glColor3f(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].colour[0],Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].colour[1],Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].colour[2]);
                if(tOn){
                glTexCoord2f (Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].tex[0], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].tex[1]);
                }
                glVertex3f(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].location[0], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].location[1], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3].location[2]);


                glColor3f(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].colour[0],Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].colour[1],Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].colour[2]);
                if(tOn){
                glTexCoord2f (Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].tex[0], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].tex[1]);
                }
                glVertex3f(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].location[0], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].location[1], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+1].location[2]);


                glColor3f(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].colour[0],Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].colour[1],Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].colour[2]);
                if(tOn){
                glTexCoord2f (Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].tex[0], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].tex[1]);
                }
                glVertex3f(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].location[0], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].location[1], Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->VBO[lj*3+2].location[2]);

                glEnd();


            }
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            */

            //####
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->vboID);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->indexvboID);


            /*
            //this could also be used BUT if glDrawElements uses the indices (m_pgroupVerticeIndex), we will need to give the array with all the 
            //vertices to glVertexPointer. That array would be m_pVertice
            //glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 5, Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->buffer);
            */


            glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


            //Get the material that belongs to this mtlGroup
            int mtlIndex = Models3D[i]->object.FindMaterial(Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->mtlName);


            //check if there was a texture for this material
            if(Models3D[i]->object.materials[mtlIndex]->texturePresent){

                glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Models3D[i]->object.materials[mtlIndex]->textureIDDiffuse);

                glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
                glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
                //glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 5, Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->buffer);
                //glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, Models3D[i]->object.m_pTexture);

            }


            // Resetup our pointers.  This doesn't reinitialise any data, only how we walk through it
            glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(20));
            glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(32));
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));



            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->m_vecgroupVerticeIndex.size()*3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

            //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->m_vecgroupVerticeIndex.size()*3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT,  Models3D[i]->object.mtlGroups[j]->m_pgroupVerticeIndex);


            glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        }


    }


}
```

My buffer contains the vertices (array of Vertex structs):

```
struct Vertex {

    GLfloat location[3];
    GLfloat tex[2];
    GLfloat normal[3];
    GLfloat colour[3];
    GLubyte padding[20];        //apparently to get 64 bytes -> improved performance


};
```

And here is how I initialize/generate buffers for each of the materials:

```
//This function was implemented based on the tutorial shown at
//http://sdickinson.com/wordpress/?p=122

void CObjLoader::GenerateVBO(){


    for(int mj=0;mj<mtlGroups.size();mj++){

        glGenBuffers(1, &mtlGroups[mj]->vboID);
        //printf("bufferID: %d", mtlGroups[mj]->vboID);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mtlGroups[mj]->vboID); // Bind the buffer (vertex array data)

        // Allocate space.  We could pass the mesh in here (where the NULL is), but it's actually faster to do it as a 
        // seperate step.  We also define it as GL_STATIC_DRAW which means we set the data once, and never 
        // update it.  This is not a strict rule code wise, but gives hints to the driver as to where to store the data
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * mtlGroups[mj]->m_vecgroupVerticeIndex.size()*3, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertex) * mtlGroups[mj]->m_vecgroupVerticeIndex.size()*3, mtlGroups[mj]->VBO); // Actually upload the data

        // Set the pointers to our data.  Except for the normal value (which always has a size of 3), we must pass 
        // the size of the individual component.  ie. A vertex has 3 points (x, y, z), texture coordinates have 2 (u, v) etc.
        // Basically the arguments are (ignore the first one for the normal pointer), Size (many components to 
        // read), Type (what data type is it), Stride (how far to move forward - in bytes - per vertex) and Offset 
        // (where in the buffer to start reading the data - in bytes)

        // Make sure you put glVertexPointer at the end as there is a lot of work that goes on behind the scenes
        // with it, and if it's set at the start, it has to do all that work for each gl*Pointer call, rather than once at
        // the end.
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(12));
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(20));
        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(32));
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

        // When we get here, all the vertex data is effectively on the card

        // Our Index Buffer, same as above, the variable needs to be accessible wherever we draw
        glGenBuffers(1, &mtlGroups[mj]->indexvboID); // Generate buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mtlGroups[mj]->indexvboID); // Bind the element array buffer
        // Upload the index array, this can be done the same way as above (with NULL as the data, then a 
        // glBufferSubData call, but doing it all at once for convenience)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mtlGroups[mj]->m_vecgroupVerticeIndex.size()*3*sizeof(GLubyte), mtlGroups[mj]->index, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    }


}
```

For the sake of simplicity, my index array looks like this: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... This means that my buffer contains some of the vertices twice. VBO and index have therefore the same length.

Maybe I am messing something up with the initialization?

Comment: Doesn't really help me understand glTexCoordPointer and it's use in conjunction with glDrawElements....

Comment: Thats correct, but is easier to help you if you use state of the art techniques.

Comment: I wanted to add VBO later on as right now I don't care about performance and only want to see whether everything would look alright. But I guess I will have to restructure the code.

Comment: If you change your code to VBO's and maybe shaders you better do it now. :-)

Comment: I adjusted my code and the question now. Something still isn't correct

Comment: It seems something is messed up with the index array. I will take a look again and report back later.

Comment: Your render code seems correct to me, but your initialization code doesn't need to use calls like `glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(20));` because it's always done when you render the scene. Is he rendering anything? Any errors?

Comment: Ok, I've found the error. Apparently, I was using GLubyte for the indices and in my case, I have way more than 255 vertices. Changing to GLuint has resolved the issue. However, my texture still isn't drawn correctly onto the object. The object stays grey. But colors seem to work.

Comment: Do I need the glClientActiveTexture command? If I plain and simply draw the texture to a quad (glBegin(GL_QUADS); and then TexCoord and Vertex3f), then the texture is displayed. So I don't think this is due to inexistant texture.

Comment: Did you enable GL_TEXTURE_2D? You don't need `glClientActiveTexture` if you are not using multiple textures.

Comment: GL_TEXTURE_2D is enabled. I think it has something to do with the .obj model that I am using. Applying the texture to all material Groups seems to yield better results.

Comment: Maybe you should open a new question for this issue and close this one because the question itself has been solved? Maybe you could edit the question itself but a new one bringts your question at the top of the newest questions.

Answer (score 1):

So the error was the following  (I will just copy my previous comments explaining the solution):

*Ok, I've found the error. Apparently, I was using GLubyte for the indices and in my case, I have way more than 255 vertices. Changing to GLuint has resolved the issue. However, my texture still isn't drawn correctly onto the object. The object stays grey. But colors seem to work.*

The .obj loader is yielding better results now and is ok with simpler models. I will do some further testing and in case of trouble, I will be back.